# This movie requires QuickTime, which is not supported by this version of iTunes. iTunes 12.0.1.26 in Yosemite

Tags: itunes, macos, video, quicktime, movie

Rented a movie from iTunes. Tried to play it. Got error: "This movie requires QuickTime, which is not supported by this version of iTunes."

Movie is 720p HD mp4.

Have tried to open the movie in QuickTime but won't open. I suspect that's a DRM issue but QuickTime isn't saying.

I'm not sure if it's related or not but once the download completed I got an iTunes error (We could not complete your iTunes Store request. An unknown error occurred (3001)).

Has anyone else seen this lately? Anyone have any ideas?

James

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here: http://support.apple.com/en-us/TS3771
Basically, you need to get iTunes to startup in 32-bit mode.

Comment: I wish it were so. Unfortunately tried that before posting. That solution appears to have worked in previous iTunes version (going back to 10.4, I guess) but now iTunes says it requires 64-bit mode.